# ES2015: call method from the construcror

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need the DOM element be added to some container when the new instance of ES2015 class created. Looks like it's impossible to call the method from the constructor.

```js
let titleCounter = 0;

  class Header{

    constructor(){

      titleCounter++;
      this.id = 'title'+titleCounter;
      this.html = `
        <div class="${this.id}" style="background-color: blue;">Title</div>
     `;

     //addDOMtoField(); // don't work
     $('#container').append(this.html);
}   
      
addDOMtoField(){
    $('#container').append(this.html);
}
  }

  let instance1 = new Header();
```

```css
#container{
  min-height: 5px;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>
  
</div>
```

Something more elegant than add `$('#container').append(this.html);` to the constructor?

Comment: `don't work` - if you look in the developer tools console, you'd see an error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, class field and method names aren't available as variable name bindings in the constructor and other methods; they can only be accessed through a reference to the instance, which can be obtained through `this`.

So, you have to use `this.addDOMtoField()` instead of just `addDOMtoField()`.

Comment: I've added some explanatory text to your answer. @TakesiTokugawaYD You can (and should) accept the answer you found the best using the grey tick symbol next to it.

Answer (score 0):

### Why I did this mistake when asked the question

Because of Java experience before ECMAScript 2015. In Java, we can omit `this` in `this.XXX` if class method/field `XXX` exists and no local variable `XXX` declared.

---

4 years passed...
Now I am the OOP and TypeScript expert.

### Call the non-static method from constructor (and other non-static methods)

It means "call the method of own instance which will be created". Directly inside the constructor and non-static-methodd, `this` keyword refers to the instance of current class. So to calling of `addDOMtoField` method is `this.addDOMtoField`.

Just `addDOMtoField` means the calling of local variable. Because there was not declared and initialized such variable, the `addDOMtoField` is `undefined`. JavaScript will no yell to it, but TypeScript will and it's right, because it's meaningless to refer to variable which has not been initialized and ever has not been declared.

Because the constructor role is the initialization of class fields, we need to understand what we doing when calling the methods from constructor. In OOP, basically the constructor must not cause any side effect.

### Call the non-static method from constructor (and other any methods)

The static method is the common for all instances. It's associated with class, not with specific instance. That's why many other languages does not forgive `this.staticMethodName()`, but JavaScript forgives and it confuses. It's recommended to forbid such invocation by ESLint.

So, the right way of static method invocation is call if from class, not from instance: `ClassName.staticMethodName()`.